# How to draw an LTS based on the parallel process "|" in CCS Milner's logic?

Tags: formal-languages, logic, ccs

I'm trying to provide a Hennessy-Milner logic formula for CCS expressions that are not (strongly) bisimilar. An example with a sketch:

> For each of the following CCS expressions, decide whether they are strongly bisimilar and if no, find a distinguishing formula in Hennessy-Milner logic.

$b.a.Nil+b.Nil$ and $b(a.Nil+b.Nil)$

I first draw these two to get a better understanding as follows (excuse my awful drawing skills but I couldn't figure out how to put it in LaTeX so I used [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)):

[image]

You can clearly see the Right Hand Side could do $b.b$ but the Left Hand Side can't respond to that. And my distinguishing HML formula is $[b]<b>tt$. On the LHS you get: $[b]\{b.a.Nil+b.Nil\} = \emptyset$ 
and on the RHS you get: 
$[b]\{b(a.Nil+b.Nil), a.Nil+b.Nil\} = b(a.Nil+b.Nil)$.
Therefore this is a valid distinguishing formula.

Hopefully, I made what the exercise is about clear. Now, the following CCS expressions that I have to distinguish are:

$a.Nil|b.Nil$ and $a.b.Nil + b.a.Nil$.

I know how to draw the RHS because the `+` denotes a choice but I don't have any idea of how the parallelism work in CCS and couldn't understand it after reading. My guess is the following but it doesn't make sense and is probably wrong:

[image]

Could someone help me understand how to sketch the LHS so that I can complete this exercise?

**P.S My tags are probably not correct but I couldn't find any tags to Hennessy-Milner logic, so feel free to edit them.**

Comment: Your last LTS is wrong, it should be a diamond-shaped graph, where on one side you perform a then b, and on the other b then a, both sides leading to Nil. Also note that if you can't distinguish between two processes, maybe they are bisimilar, and you could try proving that instead.

Comment: @chi Like this https://imgur.com/a/p78PUVj ?

Comment: @chi If my drawing is correct, then your comment is exactly what I needed. Please feel free to add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: And maybe it's an idea to introduce `Hennessy–Milner logic` tag? You can do it as you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last LTS in your question is wrong. It should be a diamond-shaped graph, where on one side you perform action $a$ then $b$, and on the other you perform action $b$ then $a$, both sides leading to $\sf Nil$.

This is because the $a$ action is run in parallel w.r.t. the $b$ action, so we get all the possible "interleavings" between such events.

The fixed LTS you posted in the comments looks right, instead.